# Most efficient way to check email extension

Tags: java, android, email, email-validation

I'm writing an application in Android that will allow a user to register for an account only if they have a specific .edu email (abc.edu for example). I started to write some code that will verify this, but now I am wondering if there are any methods that would make this easier. I've only taken beginner Java/Programming courses, so I am not sure if what I'm doing is completely wrong way of going about this.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
Get length of inputted email.
if (
email.charat(length)-1 = u &&
email.charat(length)-2 = d &&
email.charat(length)-3 = e &&
email.charat(length)-4 = . &&
email.charat(length)-5 = c &&
email.charat(length)-6 = b &&
email.charat(length)-7 = a )

Success
else
Not a valid email
```

Comment: Don't look for *efficient*, look for *readable* and *maintainable*. And the above is not it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java String class has an [`endsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method you could be using:

```
if (email.endsWith("abc.edu") { ... }
```

If you have an Editable, you could:

```
if (email.toString().endsWith("abc.edu")) { ... }
```

If you want that case-insensitively, just do:

```
if (email.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith("abc.edu")) { ... }
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm using the Editable class and it doesn't seem to support the `endsWith` class. I have to use "Editable" and not "String" as I am retrieving the text from user input.

Comment: @EGHDK: edited. Note that your pseudo-code does work, and can be made a bit more general by using some form of list (or even a string) for the chars you want to compare with, and a loop rather than a long comparison chain.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Lastly, do you know of how I could implement the ignoreCase function? If I use a capital ABC it throws off the function, but lowercase abc does now work. Thanks again

Comment: @EGHDK: edited. Just lowercase your input. (This will not change your Editable, that will keep its original value.)

Comment: Did not know toLowerCase was a method. Hahaha. Thanks Mat, I really appreciate it!